# Calculating the midpoint for numerical integration

Tags: python, arrays, integration, numeric

I am trying to write some code to do numerical integration using the midpoint method.  A and b are the bounds of integration. I keep getting only one value in my midpoint list. I want python to look at the list of my values and calculate the midpoint for all values in the list.

This is what I want:
binlist = [1,2,3,4]
midpoint = [1.5,2.5,3.5]

```
a=0 
b=5
bins=10 #Number of bins

binnumber = np.linspace(a,b,bins)  
binlist = binnumber.tolist() 
midpoint= []  

for elements in range(10): 
    i=0
    midpoint1 = (binlist[i+1]-binlist[i])/2
    midpoint.append(midpoint1) 
    i+=1

print(midpoint)
```

Comment: The question is not clear.. What is your expectation?

Comment: Sorry. Essentially I want the program to look at my list of values and calculate the midpoint between each of the values.      For example: a=[1,2,3,4] midpoint=[1.5,2.5,3.5]

Comment: Think carefully about the value that `i` has at each point in the process. Also consider what value `elements` will have at each point in the process, and then consider whether you actually *use* that value for anything, and whether you *could* use that value for anything.

Comment: Also please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thank you for the link. The mistake was in the logic of calculating the midpoint. I was not adding the difference back to the ith value hence I got the same value again and again. Secondly, if I have a list of 10 points, I should get a list of 9 midpoints. And yes, I did not need to iterate with i, I could just use 'elements' in the code and that would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
n = 0
output = []

for x in range(len(l) -1):
    n = (l[x] + l[x+1]) /2
    output.append(n)
    
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I saw that I was placing my definition of i in the wrong place. The code was redefining i every time the loop ran.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is with the following

`midpoint1 = (binlist[i+1]-binlist[i])/2`

It shoulf be:
`midpoint1 = (binlist[i+1]+binlist[i])/2`

You should be adding the elements in the list then dividing

The following code produces the desired output

```
import numpy as np
a=0.0
b=5.0
bins=10 #Number of bins

binnumber = np.linspace(a,b,bins)
binlist = binnumber.tolist() 
midpoint= []
i = 0
while i < len(binlist)-1:
   
    
    midpoint1 = (binlist[i+1]+binlist[i])/2
    midpoint.append(midpoint1)
    i +=1
            
print(midpoint)
```